# How to make xampp not show directory listing?

Tags: php, xampp

I have a url "678.345.45.23/login" to access my login page. 
And I have placed my login.php in htdocs/trial/login/login.php.

Therefore if I put "678.345.45.23/trial/login" it is listing all the file names in login folder.

I don't want to display the file names and folder names. How can I make in such a way that if I put any folder name in url it should take only the actual file name

Comment: what an unusual ip address ;-) ~ add a rule to your `htaccess` file that uses `login.php` as your directory index file or change the name from `login.php` to `index.php`

Comment: It is a fake IP..:) @RamRaider

Comment: I have got a solution in the referred link@DieterKräutl

Answer (score 0):

Using an .htaccess file, you can change the index file to something else other than any of the index defaults listed above. To do this, insert the following line into an .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex login.php
```